# Firebase Push Notification opens activity without clicking

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I have an issue with firebase push notifications.
Instead of seing the notificication, it opens automatically the activity I put. I want this behavior, but after clicking the notification.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    final String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    final String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    showNotifications(title, message);
}

private void showNotifications(String title, String msg) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, OrderDetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("order_id", 99);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_logo)
            .build();

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    try {
        pendingIntent.send();
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a quick look, I'm wondering why do you need `pendingIntent.send();`? From the docs on [send()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send()):

> Perform the operation associated with this PendingIntent.

That's why its probably executing the `Intent` attached. Try remove that line. See [Create a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) for more.